# injected codes works for most webpages, but not youtube...?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a simple extension to inject real-time clock on current web page. It works for most web pages, google.com, hulu.com, stackoverflow.com..., but not youtube.com, I don't know why.

Here is the manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "Insert Timestamp",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2, 
"description": "Insert Timestamp",
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" },
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "unlimitedStorage"],

"content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "css" : ["show.css"],
    "js" : ["cbd.js", "ccc.js"]
}]
}
```

the cbd.js calls functions in ccc.js "onload" to get real-time and display the time in a div.

and show.css is also quite simple:

```
#showme {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999999;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

I'm not familiar with web page stuff, just guessing: maybe youtube put something on top level which covers my clock?

----------------- java script codes added here ------------------
(1)cbd.js

```
window.onload = function() { startTime(); }
```

(2)ccc.js

```
var div = document.createElement("showme");
div.id = "showme";
document.body.appendChild(div);
  document.getElementById('showme').style.color = 'red';
  document.getElementById('showme').style.fontSize = '32pt';

function startTime() 
{ 
    var today=new Date(); 
    var h=today.getHours(); 
    var m=today.getMinutes() 
    var s=today.getSeconds(); 
    var w=today.getMilliseconds()%1000;

    h=checkTime(h); 
    m=checkTime(m); 
    s=checkTime(s); 
    w=checkMS(w);

    document.getElementById('showme').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s+":"+w;

    t=setTimeout('startTime()',1); 
} 

function checkTime(i) 
{ 
    if (i<10) 
    {i="0" + i;} 
        return i; 
} 

function checkMS(i) 
{ 
    if ((i>9)&&(i<100) )
        {i="0" + i;} 
    else if(i<10)
        {i="00" + i;} 
    else
        {}
    return i; 
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the page's console for any errors?

Comment: Probably `#showme` is some element you're injecting/manipulating inside the DOM, and it gets removed/reloaded when YouTube updates the page via AJAX + `history.pushState()`. By the way **add the JavaScript code** you're using and tell us what would be the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi, Xan, Yes I did and errors were fixed before it worked on web pages like google.com.

Comment: Hi, Marco, Yes, "#showme" is the element I want to inject. And java codes added above. what I'm expecting can be seen in here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insert-timestamp/hojacnchclkfkdkcadnfogedeppclijb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon, I hope that real-time clock in red can be seen in any webpage I open in chrome.

Comment: Why do you need the `onload` wrapper? See [`run_at` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), especially the note.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, just tried using "run_at": "document_end" without "onload", the script doesn't automatically loaded to web page...?